# Ghost of dead husband tries to play Cupid for widow

Tags: identify-this-movie

I can only recall a few scenes and details from the movie :-

- 80's / 90's TV movie.
- Happy married couple, husband is a pilot (if not mistaken).
- Husband dies in a plane crash (if not mistaken).
- Husband's ghost takes care of his wife by finding the right guy for her ( the guy is a soldier ).
- Wife meets a guy which is set up by the dead husband.
- Wife try to impress the guy through dinner which she did not cook at all. Only order takeouts but makes it looked like she is cooking.
- Dead husband made the guy rub his left eyebrow and the wife notices that action because that is her husband habit.
- There is a scene where the wife felt the husband is there so she started to dance and the dead husband dances with her.

I really love this movie and I watched it like when I was 10. Please help to identify this film.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be Steven Spielberg's [Always](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096794/), (1989).  Richard Dreyfuss is an aerial firefighter who dies fighting a forest fire, and Holly Hunter is his girlfriend.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Always_%281989_film%29):

> the spirit of a recently dead expert pilot mentors a newer pilot,
>   while watching him fall in love with his surviving girlfriend.

Comment: this is where I was going to go.

Comment: OMGGG...thank youuu...this is it... Always (1989) ....THANKS WILL!!

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the [M.I.A. - April 1, 1969 (S02E22)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096684/episodes?season=2&ref_=tt_eps_sn_2) episode of [Quantum Leap](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096684/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)? It matches several of the bullet points you listed.

- Husband appears like a ghost (though he is really a hologram from the future).
- Aired on TV during the 80's / 90's.
- Happy married couple, and husband is a pilot.
- Husband was presumed dead (though he did not die in a plane crash).
- Husband (and friend) find a guy for her to fall in love with (guy was a cop)
- At the end of the episode, the husband and wife dance, and she feels like he is there.

  [image: Beth and Al dancing]

Some points I know that don't match are

- It was a TV show episode not a movie, though the episode is over 48 minutes long, so it could easily be mistaken as one if you weren't familiar with the show.
- Husband did not die in a plane crash.
- Guy was not a soldier. He was a cop. Wife was in the navy I believe though.

Comment: talkingcat mentioned movie or drama before coleopterist's edit, shows that he is confuse between movie or tv series. So it looks a match +1.

Comment: @AnkitSharma it's a very tricky call for me because of the premise of the TV show. However, talkingcat said he watched it when he was 10 years old. So, I can see how a lot of the discrepencies could be easily confused.

Comment: THANKS druciferre, but it was a movie... Always (1989)...